# Convergence with the recurrence $T_{n+1}=T_n^2-T_n+\frac{n}{p_n}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, recurrences

For each integer $n\geq 1$ I define the recurrence $$T_{n+1}=T_n^2-T_n+\frac{n}{p_n},$$
with $T_1=1$, where $p_k$ denotes the $k$-th prime.

So multiplying by $(-1)^n$ and telescoping gives that for each integer $n\geq 1$, $$T_1+(-1)^n T_n=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k T_k^2+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k k}{p_k}.$$

**Do the sequences $(-1)^n T_n$, and $\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k T_k^2$ converge?**

This is similar to the Putnam problem 2.25 in (1) and section **E7** of (2),and an unsolved problem due to Erdős as in the MathWorld article on [Prime Sums.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSums.html)

### References:

(1) Valentin Boju and Louis Funar, *The Math Problems Notebook*, Birkhäuser (2007).

(2) Richard K. Guy, Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, Unsolved problems in Intuitive Mathematics Volume I, Second Edition, Springer-Verlag (1994).

Comment: $T_n$ seems to be asymptotic to about $1/(2\log n)$, both numerically and by thinking about the recurrence. More precisely it's presumably asymptotic to $n/(2\mathop{\rm li}^{-1}(n))$ where li$(n)$ is the logarithmic integral. The fluctuations are presumably on a scale about $1/\sqrt n$ smaller than that (if the Riemann hypothesis is true). So I'm guessing that the series is close enough to an alternating series, with decreasing $T_k^2$, that the series converges.

Comment: Many thanks to you and the user improving the edit of my post. Feel free to add your reasoning and thoughts as an answer, it sure is very interesting for all users interested in recurrences involving prime numbers @GregMartin

Comment: Many thanks for your edits @Ycor